# Networking and CRC confusion

Tags: networking, crc

I am currently working on a project that requires data to be sent from A to B. Once B receives the data, it needs to be able to determine if an error occurred during transmission.

I have read about CRC and have decided that CRC16 is right for my needs; I can chop the data into chunks and send a chunk at a time.

However, I am confused about how B will be able to tell if an error occurred. My initial thought was to have A generate a CRC and then send the data to B. Once B receives the data, generate the CRC and send it back to A. If the CRCs match, the transmission was successful. BUT - what if the transmission of the CRC from B to A errors? It seems redundant to have the CRC sent back because it can become corrupted in the same way that the data can be.

Am I missing something or over-complicating the scenario?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks,
P

Comment: It seems that you are not understanding how CRCs work.  There is no need to send a CRC back and forth.  Once B receives the data and uses the CRC to verify the data integrity, there is no need to send it back.

Answer (score 1):

You usually send the checksum *with* the data. Then you calculate the checksum out of the data on the receiving end, and compare it with the checksum that came along with it. If they don't match, either the data or the checksum was corrupted (unless you're unlucky enough to get a collision) - in which case you should ask for a retransmission.

Comment: Actually you should compute the checksum over the received data concatened with the received checksum: the result should be zero.

Comment: EJP - could you elaborate? By checksum, I assume you mean the CRC? I don't understand what you mean by concatenating the computed checksum with the sent checksum?

Answer (score 1):

CRC is error-detection and, notice, your code can only detect a *finite* number of errors. However, you can calculate the probability of a CRC16 collision (this is relatively small for most practical purposes).

Now how CRC works is using polynomial division. Your CRC value is some polynomial (probably on the order of (x^15) for CRC16). That said, the polynomial is represented in binary as the coefficients. For example, x^3 + [(0)*x^2] + x + 1 = 1011 is some polynomial on order x^3. Now, you divide your data chunk by your CRC polynomial. The remainder is the CRC value. Thus, when you do this division operation again to the received chunk (with the remainder) on B, the polynomial division should come out even to 0. If this does not occur then you have a transmission error.

Now, this assumes (including corruption of your CRC value) that if n bits are corrupted, the CRC check will detect the failure (assuming no collision). If the CRC check does not pass, simply send a retransmission request to A. Otherwise, continue processing as normal. If a collision occurred, there is no way to verify the data is corrupted until you look at your received data manually (or send several, hopefully error-free copies - note that this method incurs a lot of overhead and redundancy only works to *finite* precision again).

Comment: Thank you for the response, RageD. I'm afraid my mathematics isn't terribly good so I'm having a bit of trouble understanding you answer fully. I was under the impression that I would need to compare the CRC generated from A and B. Will C (above) states that device B simply uses the CRC to verify data integrity. I don't understand how this can be possible without a reference data set (or, comparing its CRC with A's).

I think (if I'm reading right) that your second paragraph is saying that device B can compare its CRC with the previous CRC it generated. Am I correct?

Comment: Have you looked at this reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_CRC? I provided a very high-level description of CRC, but this goes into some better depth. I can provide a mathematical example if this is still confusing (although the mathematics we do "by hand" does not exactly correspond to the algorithm - it is merely for understanding).

Comment: Quite a bit of reading there. I will set aside some time and wade my way through it. It appears that this CRC business is not as simple as I thought. For the record, though, I have several implementations that produce a CRC value; I am treating these as black boxes. I am trying to figure out how to use the values at either end (A and B). Thanks again, I shall return once I have read the article you suggested.

Comment: @protectedmember You don't have to understand the mathematics. You just have to use it.